# Google App Engine - Serving video url's from Google Cloud Storage Error in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-app-engine, video

I'm developing an app locally right now in Google App Engine in which users can upload videos. I've set up the Google Cloud Storage library and set the read-access to public.

In the dev server, you can access the files via the URL: http://localhost:8080/_ah/gcs/bucket/filename

I'm trying to serve the files in a video HTML tag but it resulting in an error in Chrome. I get the message: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error). The server console shows the request for the file fails.

This only happens in Chrome and works fine in other browsers.

Any idea why this would be happening? It's a little hard to debug.

Comment: All requests should go directly to the Cloud Storage, so you won't/shouldn't  see anything in your server logs. Why is a server involved?

Comment: @Andrei Volgin I'm not exactly sure. I simply entered the URL as the src value in the video tag. Here are the server logs:

Request to `/_ah/gcs/app_default_bucket/5733953138851840/user/IMG_2551.mp4 failed`
`default: "GET /_ah/gcs/app_default_bucket/5733953138851840/user/IMG_2551.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 500`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a URL that leads to a Cloud Storage object. It looks like:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/YOUR_BUCKET/YOUR_OBJECT
```

Look in the Console to get the name of your default app bucket. Usually it's the same as your app id.

Comment: I'm testing right now in the dev server.

In the dev server, the URLs are: `http://localhost:8080/_ah/gcs/bucket/filename`

The URLs work on all browsers except Chrome.

Comment: I read the docs. Because I set `x-goog-acl` to `public-read`, I believe I'm using Cloud Storage API referenced in the docs. The public URLS can be accessed via `https://storage.googleapis.com/YOUR_BUCKET/YOUR_OBJECT` but I believe in dev it can be accessed via `http://localhost:8080/_ah/gcs/bucket/filename`. As I said, the links worked in other browsers, it just did not work in Chrome.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: If you get a 500 server error, it has nothing to do with Chrome - or any browser. You are hitting your server instead of getting the file directly from the Cloud Storage - that is the root of the problem.